Set Default values in Sitecore Content Hub for Content Entity
Is any out-of-the-box setting available in Sitecore Content Hub for the Content entity?
We can set the default values in Assets from the creation component and upload files section.
Content Hub – Manage Creation
I am looking for a similar kind of option for a Content entity.

https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2024/08/set-default-values-in-sitecore-content-hub-dam-cmp.html

You can set default values for the content entities, inside the Creation component for the Work page.
Inside the New Entities tab in the Creation component on the Work page, you can set default values for different Content types in your Sitecore CMP architecture as below.

Using above changes, once you create content from Work page, default values will be auto pouplated based on the content type of the page.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.
